# Google cloud dataflow java API not reading other project's pubsub topic

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow, apache-beam-io

I have only one topic which was created in the production project. I want to run my dataflow job in dev environment which needs to consume production pubsub topic. When I submit my dataflow job in dev project it is not working and it always shows running in dataflow UI but not reading any elements from pubsub. If I submit to production project it works perfectly.

Why it is not reading messages from different project topic? I'm using java-sdk 2.1 and runner is "dataflowrunner"

```
PCollection<String> StreamData = p.apply("Read pubsub message",PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(options.getInputPubSub()));
```

Using mvn to submit dataflow job

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=dataflow.streaming.SampleStream  -Dexec.args="—project=project-dev-1276 --stagingLocation=gs://project-dev/dataflow/staging --tempLocation=gs://project-dev/dataflow/bq_temp  --zone=europe-west1-c  --bigQueryDataset=stream_events --bigQueryTable=events_sample --inputPubSub=projects/project-prod/subscriptions/stream-events --streaming=true --runner=dataflowRunner"
```

Note: If I am using directrunner it works and consumes messages from different project pubsub topic.
[image]

No elements added in the queue and no estimated size.

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `Pub/Sub Subscriber` permissions in your production project for a user (a service account) that your job will use. By default, workers use your project’s Compute Engine service account as the controller service account. This service account (`<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`) should be given `Pub/Sub Subscriber` permission.

Read more here https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions and here https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/access-control